# Custom serialisation of a JSON object at the primitives level

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

I have a JS class construct called TypedValue. It comprises a "fundamental type" property and a "value" property. The fundamental type is one of seven (at present) types (expressed as a string): boolean, string, date, datetime, time, integer, decimal.

When I send a "TypedValue" to my web tier, I am looking for an efficient means of representation using JSON. The desired outcome of whatever representation I build is that it is relatively efficient and at the receiving end the fundamental type can be re-determined by the web tier.

String and Boolean are no problem - they can be sent "vanilla".

JSON has no specific representation for Date/DateTime/Time so we encode those as an object { type: "typename", value: "valuestring" }.

Which leaves me with the integer/decimal fundamental types. These can also be sent vanilla except for one particular case, which is the reason for this question:

If I have a TypedValue of fundamental type integer, I can send it as vanilla JSON. The receiver knows it is an integer because there is no decimal point sent.

If I have a TypedValue of fundamental type decimal, and the value has a fractional/decimal part, I can send it as vanilla JSON. The receiver knows it is a decimal because there is a decimal point and decimal part in the number.

So that leaves a TypedValue which holds a whole number but whose fundamental type is decimal. For example, 23.

If I send the value as 23 (which is how JSON would encode it) the receiver will think the implied fundamental type of the number is integer, not decimal.

The solution is fairly obvious, of course: to send the number as 23. or 23.0 instead of 23, so the receiver knows it is a decimal number.

*However*, and this is the purpose of my question, I can see no way of actually achieving this because the JSON serialisation mechanics never [appear to] let me control how a primitive value gets encoded.

I can write a toJSON( ) method on my TypedValue class, but I can only return a different data structure to be serialised. There is no way I can do this:

- If the fundamental type is "decimal" and my value is a whole number, emit the primitive value with a .0 on the end.

My "workaround" at present is to encode the "whole number decimal" as { type: "decimal", value: 23 } so the receiver gets explicitly told the type is a decimal even though the value "looks like" an integer. But damn it's ugly, more so because it is a corner case and all the other numeric cases pan-out fine.

Now, I know I *could* write my own serialiser but I simply have too strong a sense of that being a "sledgehammer cracking walnut" kind of approach. It also means anyone else who potentially used this API would be forced into the same situation. Ideally I want to find a simple solution that incorporates standard JSON.stringify behaviour (if possible).

I know some people might ask "why are you concerned about recovering the fundamental type" on the web tier as means to side-step the problem altogether, but I don't really want this question to be about that. Nonetheless, I will offer a rationale, being that our JSON web api front-ends an internal C# Database API, and that API expects data of the correct types. In other words, integer database fields expect integer data types, and so forth. For our "JSON web api layer" to perform conversions requires it to have knowledge of the database schema, or otherwise the C# Database API needs to perform the conversions. Both of these are under consideration, alongside the issue I have raised here.

Comment: Have you considered other serialization schemes like [Universal Binary JSON](http://ubjson.org/) or [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/)?

Comment: Not very pretty, but have you considered adopting a naming scheme for properties so that the actual type be known from the property name (e.g. strName, nAge, dWeight)?

Comment: Is every single value composed of TypedValue instances, or do you have a mixed usage of JS types + TypedValue? Specifically, do you pass a regular JS object/array with a bunch of TypedValue values as properties/items to the serializer, or do you have "map" and "array" types for top-level TypedValue objects?

Comment: I recommend you use `{type: "type", value: primitive/string}` or `{"type": primitive/string}` as @AtesGoral suggested to serialize all your `TypedValue`s. Yes it's more verbose but all things considered, it is not going to make that much of a difference. The important part is that you optimize how the data is stored in the database. Serializing it this way also gives you some consistency to work with so that you don't have to consider edge cases like this in the future, you'll always be given the type explicitly.